# Is the WebSocket returned from HttpContext.WebSockets.AcceptWebSocketAsync thread-safe?

Tags: asp.net-core, websocket

In ASP.NET Core v2, is the `WebSocket` returned by [HttpContext.WebSockets.AcceptWebSocketAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.websocketmanager.acceptwebsocketasync?view=aspnetcore-2.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Http_WebSocketManager_AcceptWebSocketAsync) thread-safe?

More specifically, can I call [`ReceiveAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.websockets.websocket.receiveasync(v=vs.110).aspx) in parallel with a thread that calls [`SendAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.websockets.websocket.sendasync(v=vs.110).aspx)?

I'd like to be able to have a message loop receiving messages like the close event, while at the same time be able to send messages in response to server-side events (that is, not in response to received events).

Comment: Yes it is, but you'll have to be careful with the shutdown code path. E.g. when you receive a close message then you need to defer your response to your sending thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't found any documentation specifying what implementation `AcceptWebSocketAsync` returns, but in practice it appears to consistently return a `ManagedWebSocket` instance.

I haven't found any API documentation for `ManagedWebSocket`. Fortunately the source code has been published and it contains this helpful note:

> Thread-safety:
>
> - It's acceptable to call ReceiveAsync and SendAsync in parallel.  One of each may run concurrently.
> - It's acceptable to have a pending ReceiveAsync while CloseOutputAsync or CloseAsync is called.
> - Attemping to invoke any other operations in parallel may corrupt the instance.  Attempting to invoke a send operation while another is in progress or a receive operation while another is in progress will result in an exception.

— [(source1)](https://github.com/aspnet/WebSockets/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebSockets/Internal/fx/src/Common/src/System/Net/WebSockets/ManagedWebSocket.cs#L22-L27)
[(source2)](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/d6b11250b5113664dd3701c25bdf9addfacae9cc/src/Common/src/System/Net/WebSockets/ManagedWebSocket.cs#L22-L28)

**tl;dr**: not thread-safe in general, but the read and send in parallel scenario is supported